# Get filename from full path in Pascal

Tags: string, path, position, inno-setup, pascal

I'm wondering how to get a file name from full path in Pascal.

In .NET, we have two functions - Path.GetFileName and String.IndexOf, both of them allow to accomplish the task.

For example, "C:\docs\file.txt" will return "file.txt".

What would be the Pascal equivalent?

Comment: What Pascal? Different compilers and implementations have different run-time libraries, and therefore offer different ways to do things. Delphi's RTL, for instance, offers ExtractFileName.

Comment: It's Inno Setup pascal scripting. The only function available I think is Pos.

Comment: Just confirmed that Inno supports ExtractFileName - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [ExtractFileName](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extractfilename) function. Thanks to Ken's comment.